# How to change the color of the background in libgdx labels?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I can change the color of the font like this

```
LabelStyle style1 = new LabelStyle(..some font..., 
                Color.valueOf("FF4500")
                );
label.setStyle(style1);
```

but how do I change the background?
right now the background is the same as the background of whole screen which is set in

render method lke this

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(
            1.000f, 0.980f, 0.941f

            ,1);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Label label = new Label(labelText, skin);
Pixmap labelColor = new Pixmap(labelWidth, labelHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
labelColor.setColor(<your-color-goes-here>);
labelColor.fill();
label.getStyle().background = new Image(new Texture(labelColor)).getDrawable();
```

Basically, use the getDrawable() function of the Image class to assign the color of your Label's LabelStyles' background Drawable.

This is the simplest workaround I've been able to come up with and, frankly, it's just silly that there is no setBackground() in the Label class.

Actually, maybe the easiest fix is to hack the Label class and add a setBackground() method to it.

[Edit] Be sure to dispose of Pixmaps when you are done with them; i.e. labelColor.dispose();

[Update] @Mitrakov Artem made a good point: The above solution will affect all instances of this LabelStyle. If that's not what you want you can create a new LabelStyle, use the above method on it, then save it to the Label. Quoting Artem: "So I would recommend to create a new style (LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(label.getStyle());), change its background and then apply it to the label (label.setStyle(style);)"

Comment: Very good solution, but you actually change the appearance of LabelStyle instance. It means all the other labels with the same style will be affected. So I would recommend to create a new style (`LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(label.getStyle());`), change its background and then apply it to the label (`label.setStyle(style);`)

Comment: @MitrakovArtem - I think that's a great improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you do not change the background of the Lable like that. You did just change the clearcolour. Guess you know that.

To change the background you need to change the background at the style of the label. To do so i'd recommend to use a simple `NinePatch` as background, (can be a square! if its white you can change the colour of the ninepatch and the background colour changes!)

```
NinePatch temp = new NinePatch(new Texture(....), 10, 10, 10, 10); //edges
```

For more information about ninepatch take a look [here libgdx wiki ninepatch](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsNinePatch)

You **need** to add that ninepatch to an Skin objekt. For example like this

```
Skin skin = new Skin();
skin.add("background",temp)
```

After that you can get a drawable from the skin that you can set as background of the `LabelStyle`.

```
style1.background = skin.getDrawable("background");
```

see [libgdx API LabelStyle](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.LabelStyle.html)

You can also use a simple bitmap but that does get scaled to the label size which causes in most of the cases deformation. A Ninepatch can be scaled without having deformation.

Comment: cant I just set a background color?

Comment: it changes the text color, thats why I asked

Comment: than you cant just change the background like that because it does not have any background. You need to add on first befor you can change it. As i said if you use a white texture you can change that colour to every colour you whish.

Comment: So much chatting on this. In short, you cannot change or set the background color of a label directly. Directly means, set directly the background a to specific color, i.e, like labelStyle.background = Color.BLACK;

Answer (score 1):

If you need a quick and easy solution, you can use the snippet below. It doesn't work well with multiline text because it doesn't take the text width per line into account. 
Anyway, the background is automatically adjusted to the width and height of the label widget (i.e. if your text changes).

```
private Label label = new Label("text", createLabelStyleWithBackground());

private LabelStyle createLabelStyleWithBackground() {
    LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle();
    labelStyle.font = new BitmapFont();
    labelStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    labelStyle.background = createBackground();
    return labelStyle;
}

private Drawable createBackground() {
    Pixmap labelColor = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    Color color = new Color(Color.GRAY);
    color.a = 0.75f;
    labelColor.setColor(color);
    labelColor.fill();

    Texture texture = new Texture(labelColor);

    return new BaseDrawable() {

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
            GlyphLayout layout = label.getGlyphLayout();
            x = label.getX();
            y = label.getY() - (layout.height + 15) / 2; // +15 is some space 
            batch.draw(texture, x, y, layout.width, layout.height + 15);
        }
    };
}
```

[here is an example with a multiline label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKrqV.png)